# Change Background Color and Icon in JFrame

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe

```
public class Board {

 static JFrame frame = new JFrame("");


 public static void Board() {

    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("icon.png");
    frame.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    frame.setSize(350, 350);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board.Board(); 
 }
}
```

It was supposed that the icon in the top left corner changed to my icon.png, and the background should be blue, but it's not happening... what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you have an error when you load the `ImageIcon` ?

Comment: No I don't . I create a source folder called "images" in this java project, and that's where I have icon.png @JeanMel

Comment: I try to put a picture in a package and set the IconImage from it... I think it works (I edited my post).

Answer (score 1):

To set the background of the frame to BLUE you have to replace this line `frame.setBackground(Color.BLUE);` by this one `frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);`

I put the picture in a package like this :

[image: Icon image]

And to set the `IconImage`, I have to retrieve the `URL` of the picture and create the `ImageIcon` from the `URL` like this :

```
URL iconURL = TestSO.class.getResource("/testso/image.png");
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

Maybe it's a bad method to put a picture in package... But I think it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change color of frame.getContentPane()